# curly braces when define array

Tags: java, arrays, curly-braces

Regards to the following code:

```
int[] to = new int[] { text };
```

I understand it tries to define an array of integer, but What does the **curly braces** do in array definition?

Comment: Yes, it looks like you are anonymously subclassing an array, but it is just an initialization

Comment: I mean if it's seen 5.5k times, it provides a decent quality content I suppose? I googled "curly braces java array" and got this. Better than scouring the ugly Java docs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The curly braces contain values to populate the array.

Comment: So, currently there is only one element which is 'text', right?

Comment: @Leem.fin, Yes, if 'text' is an int - there will be an array 'to' created with one element which is 'text'.

Answer (score 21):

This is just a shortcut code to create an array with initial elements, the followings (which are equal):

```
    int[] to = new int[] { text };
    int[] to = { text };
```

can be substituted with

```
    int[] to = new int[1];
    to[0] = text;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: After 4 years of Java development, I'm only discovering this syntax now. I don't understand why it's not used more. It's so much easier and more sexy than the way that's shown in all the docs - declaration, then manually setting each element in the array.

Answer (score 10):

This syntax allows you to define the contents of an array and is often referred to as an array literal.

In this context this can actually be simplified to:

```
int[] to = { 1, 2, 7, etc. };
```

Adding `new int[]` before it is only required when not part of an assignment, something like:

```
someFunction(new int[]{1, 3, 5});
```

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces said to the compiler the values of the array

Comment: So, currently there is only one element which is 'text', right?

Answer (score 0):

Like SLaks said, curly braces is a way Java denotes a set. You can define the contents of the array using this method, but each element you define has to be the same type as the array.